# Does TurboTax store information locally if tax file is saved removable media

Tags: privacy

Does TurboTax store "sensitive" or "personal information" locally if tax file is saved on removable media?

Comment: What version of TurboTax? It might be a stupid question, since you can’t to my knowledge use older versions, to submit  your current years taxes but in retrospect it might matter in a year

Comment: Generally not.  I use Turbo Tax, have my own tax folder structure and that is where the data is.   Beware temporary registry entries for TT and Adobe, but these should just be filenames.

Comment: @John The filenames I could understand. I mostly worried about temp files.

Comment: I do not see temp files after the tax file has been saved and TT closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your tax files are stored wherever you saved them.

If you wish to be sure, search for `*.tax` files on your local disk.

The default folder is usually `Documents\TurboTax`.